# Quoting a previous answer to a possible duplicate of the question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/583059/is-this-a-filesystem-bug-how-can-i-remove-this-file/583060#583060) is a new one on me.  It seemed like a duplicate of an earlier question to me, so I flagged it as such, then this chap comes along and posts an answer agreeing with me, quoting Zoredache's excellent accepted answer to the earlier question, and saying very little else besides.

I don't have any idea what the right action is now.  Leave it to stand?  Edit it out?  Nominate it for deletion?  Flag it?

Comment: Not sure if they're trying to be helpful (or farm easy rep) to the person asking the question or they don't understand the implication of the close vote & comment linking the questions. Oh, and VTC'd

Comment: I'm not sure about that, either.

Comment: Question needs another VTC, and answer needs another downvote before becoming delete-vote eligible, which is who I think we should handle this.

Comment: As i was that chap the three reasons RobM write on the comment are exactly the reason.

Comment: Fair enough, old chap!  Hopefully, the procedure is now clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already have a mechanism for closing duplicates so I don't believe that it is necessary or desirable to quote an existing answer as your own (even if it's your own iyswim).

I left a comment for the OP regarding this and hopefully they will avoid doing the same in the future.

With any luck a mod will drive by and clean it all up close/merge it into the original Q&A.

Comment: Exactly. Whenever I feel like reusing an answer, that question is a strong candidate for being closed as duplicate of the other question.